# Stop Firefox starting with two tab open

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

I've been all over the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) trying to find out which command line arguments or userpreferences will prevent firefox from starting with two tabs open and also stop asking would I like to share usage statistics.

Here's a screenshot
[image]

What command line argument or user preference can I set to stop Firefox browser from starting like that when I provide the `-new-instance` flag?

**[edit]**
I am on FreeBSD but linux instructions should be fine as well. I am running the latest version of Firefox, this image is firefox 50.1

I launch firefox like this after I first create `"/path/to/profile/prefs.js"`

```
firefox -marionette -profile "/path/to/profile" -new-instace
```

that profile only does a few things, basically sets up marionette

```
marionette_prefs_enabled = "user_pref(\"marionette.defaultPrefs.is_enabled\", true);\n"
marionette_prefs_port = "user_pref(\"marionette.defaultPrefs.port\", %d);\n"%(proc_port)
marionette_prefs_startup_page = "user_pref(\"browser.startup.page\", false);\n"
marionette_prefs_upload_enabled = "user_pref(\"datareporting.healthreport.uploadEnabled\", false);\n"
marionette_prefs_service_enabled = "user_pref(\"datareporting.healthreport.service.enabled\", false);\n"
marionette_prefs_service_first_run = "user_pref(\"datareporting.healthreport.service.firstRun\", false);\n"
marionette_prefs_service_first_run2 = "user_pref(\"toolkit.telemetry.reportingpolicy.firstRun\", false);\n"
profile_path = '-profile \"%s\"'%(path)
```

as you can see, i've tried to disable a bunch of those things from the documentation i've found on the mozilla site but they still do not work. Hence this question.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you on? You should just be able to click those three horizontal bars at the top right, select Preferences, and then from the General tab, choose what happens "When Firefox Starts"

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I would agree with you but the "Choose What I Share" banner at the bottom suggests that OP's FireFox acts like a fresh install every time they open their browser.

Comment: @user1610950 Please specify your operating system.

Comment: Hi guys, I updated the question, the os is FreeBSD, Firefox 50.1